# Foreground color not updating on a selected row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, converters

I hope that some of you might have encountered the issue and can explain me what is going on here. I have tried a few fixes (within the MVVM world:) which did not help and I would like to understand the issue before applying some hack if necessary,

I have a set of three data grid columns that use a value converter for foreground color - green for positive, red for negative.

That works fine most of the time but sometimes (really cannot tell when and why) it does not. That can happen after around 20 minutes of running correctly with the application window not active (users look at the screen but do not interact with it).

One important piece of information is that whenever user clicks on the row the colours get fixed immediately.

Also it might be worth noticing that entire row colours do not update and numbers are correct....

All the updates to the property are done with BeginInvoke on the dispatcher and might happen very often (around 20 times per second).

[image: Wrong colour from the foreground binding]

Any ideas welcome.

(previously I thought it might be virtualization but this did not help)

```
<DataGrid
  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
  IsReadOnly="True"
  AlternatingRowBackground="#E5E5E5"
  EnableRowVirtualization="False"
  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
```

**Data grid column**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}" Header="A" Width="85" FontWeight="Bold">
  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource NotSelectableCellStyle}">
      <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding A, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**Converter**

```
public class NegativePositiveColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Brush negativeBrush;

    private static readonly Brush positiveBrush;

    static NegativePositiveColorConverter()
    {
        negativeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        positiveBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        negativeBrush.Freeze();
        positiveBrush.Freeze();
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        decimal? decimalValue = value as decimal?;
        if (!decimalValue.HasValue)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        if (decimalValue < 0)
        {
            return negativeBrush;
        }

        return positiveBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Source object property**

```
    public decimal? A
    {
        get
        {
            return this.a; 
        }

        set 
        {                                    
            if (this.a!= value)
            {
                this.a= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("A");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Cell Style (rather not important)**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="NotSelectableCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource EditableBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NotSelectableDataGridCellTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="NotSelectableDataGridCellTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
    <Grid>
        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Border>            
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: In any case, I would first add some logging/tracing to both the `Convert` method and `A` setter, and would log all `decimal` values which enter both methods, to see if the `Convert` is being invoked or not whenever the property gets changed. You will want to log times, thread ID's and values.

Comment: Note that the binding source for the number and the colour is the same so PropertyChanged must have been invoked in order to change the number.

Comment: Try DataTrigger instead of Converter.

Comment: @Bizz, would you care to explain how the user would define a `DataTrigger` that can tell whether a value is more or less than zero?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation! Of course you can add a boolean to your class and update it when value is changed. But the question is not how, The problem with your code seems to be related to async updates which somehow behave out of order. so one quick guess is to use a different approach to see if it's still behaving in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have found the problem thanks to (seems obvious but for some reasons I did not follow that path before) the suggestion from @Groo. I have just added a lot of logging in the converters and property setters and noticed that for one of the rows converters are never executed unless I click on the grid surface.

This happened for the row that was representing the selected item (and each time it was a different row depending on which one was added first).

Because my style does not show selection (see 'Cell Style (rather not important)' part of my question) I would not notice anything particular about the failing row.

I believe that one possible fix is to set SelectedItem to null whenever any item is selected. Why the foreground is not updated when the item is selected I am not sure.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but does it work if you add (duplicate) the same foreground binding inside the `IsSelected` trigger?

Comment: Thanks @Groo, I might try the thing with the trigger. After experimenting a bit more I realized that any selection prevents foreground colours to be updated (I could even prevent the whole grid from refreshing foreground colours when I used Extended selection mode and shift-selected everything. I added IsHitTestVisible=false to the cell style and now the only way to break it is to tab stop on the grid and select a row.